# How to remove watermark using PHP?

Tags: php, watermark

How to remove watermark using PHP? Image with watermark: http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/2771/32377509.jpg

Comment: _should_ you remove the watermark?  What does it mean?

Comment: Non-trivial. Use Photoshop, or don't steal other sites images. The watermark is there for a reason.

Comment: You should first ask yourself *why* there is a watermark, and if removing it is *legal*. If it is, the easiest way would be to ask the author of the image to provide you one without the watermark.

Comment: Wow, closed in 2 minutes. SO works great!

Comment: That was an on-topic question IMNSHO - even though it was very scarce on data, and the answer is "can't do that".

Comment: The best way to do this, would be to lay the headphones on a white piece of paper than take the picture. :):)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02Ywt87OpS4

Answer (score 10):

The watermark is there for a reason. The same reason why it will be close to impossible for you to remove it.

Comment: I won't get into ethics. But nothing is impossible mate :)

Answer (score 6):

It would be tough to do this in Photoshop, let alone using GD or something along those lines. If you're looking for image manipulation however, read up on GD:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 2):

You can't (not reliably or automatically anyway). That's the whole purpose of a watermark: take two images (watermark and base), and combine them. Some information from both is irretrievably lost, and a resulting watermarked image is produced.

You could retouch the resulting image manually, guessing and repainting what probably was in the base image, but there is no way to subtract the watermark from the watermarked image and get the original back.

See a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537070/how-can-i-process-an-image-to-remove-a-watermark-within-my-iphone-application/4546912) for an example.